# Missing interface from installed packages (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pusher

I've been trying to get used to using Typescript recently. I noticed that every time I installed a package and use it, certain props will have Typescript screaming at me that it doesn't exist in the interface the package's developers did.

Here's an example, I installed Pusher-js, then implement it like so;

```
    var pusher = new Pusher("API_KEY", {
      cluster: "ap1",
      encrypted: true,
    });
```

Then there would be an error on the encrypted prop:

```
Argument of type '{ cluster: string; encrypted: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'encrypted' does not exist in type 'Options'.ts(2345)
```

So I went to options.d.ts in Pusher-js node_modules and sure enough encrypted was not defined in the interface. I suppose I can edit that one but obviously it'll get overwritten when I update my packages.

My first thought is Pusher-js devs must have missed this, but then I'd install another different package and there's the same issue. Certain props are missing! So there must be something wrong with my typescript settings and I'm feeling completely overwhelmed right now since I just started learning typescript. What is the general practice when facing this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you just have to install the `types` package of the package in question.

```
// this is an example of a default package.json 
// when you set up a new Angular-Project.
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1"
```

As you can see even here one needs sometimes types-packages to be installed.

And here is the types package you are searching for:

```
npm install --save @types/pusher-js
```

Comment: I see, is that a common thing to do when we use Typescript for React? I'll try it out soon and let you know, thanks!

Comment: And why don't they have it on to begin with anyway? Seems unnecessary to install more things when they could have just add it in into the interface?

Comment: Solved, kinda. Turns out Pusher already deprecated the encrypted prop a long time ago. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/60e09cf45a3f8bb0167b7696205241a9726e3259

Thanks for the help.